# Importing a single object into Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-backups

I have a Firebase realtime database which looked like this:

[image]

I accidentally deleted an object - the object denoted "bayHogk..._13".

Luckily, I have a full database export in a JSON file from before the delete, so I can restore the entire database by clicking the three dots at the top-right and choosing "Import JSON".

However, since the deletion, other parts of the database have changed, and they will be overridden by the import.

My question is: is there a way to restore from the JSON, only the specific object that were deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can write some code to parse the JSON export, find only the objects you want to update, and perform those updates yourself.  There is no tool or system provided by Firebase that will do this for you.